# (JWT) Extract access token both from cookies and authorization headers?

Tags: jwt

I read that JWT is used when we want our server to handle auth in both web app and mobile app. In web app, a lot of people recommend storing both `access token` and `refresh token` in a `HttpOnly` cookie.

However, a mobile app does not have cookies, therefore, our access token must be sent via `Authorization` header.

Does that mean now in the server, I have to check both `Authorization` header and `cookies` for `access_token`?

I'm eager for some enlightenment

Comment: In this scenario yea for me you need to check both Authorization header and cookie for the token for your app, but prioritize the Authorization header first, than check if  there is  a cookie for your logic if no header exist